# Node.js - App will only load one user on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app that works on dev, but when I try it on Heroku, it will only load one user. It doesn't matter who logs in, "guestuser" is always signed in, and therefore whoever logs in gets to see 'guestusers' data. This my first go at a real node app. 
Here is the code:

```
 /**
 * Module dependencies
 */

var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    api = require('./routes/api'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = module.exports = express();

var uristring = 
process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 
process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || 
'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
  if (err) { 
  console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
  } else {
  console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
  }
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Tasks = new Schema({
    "title": String,
    "description": String,
    "difficulty": Number,
    "completed": Boolean
}); 

var Project = new Schema({
    "title": String,
    "tasks": [ Tasks ]
});

var User = new Schema({ // update data model here
    "first_name": String,
    "last_name": String,
    "email": {type: String, unique: true},
    "username": {type: String, unique: true},
    "password": String,
    "projects": [ Project ]
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);
UserModel.prototype.validPassword = function(pass) {
    return (this.password === pass);
}

/**
 * Configuration
 */

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboardcat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(passport.session());

// development only
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// production only
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  // TODO
};

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    UserModel.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {    
      if (err) { 
        console.log('There was an error');
        return done(err); 
      }
      if (!user) {
        console.log('Username invalid');
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        console.log('Password incorrect');
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


/**
 * Routes
 */

// serve index and view partials
app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.user);
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.render('login');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.body.username;
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.render('signup');   
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
app.post('/signup', function(req,res) {
    if (req.body.username && req.body.password) {
        var user = new UserModel({
            first_name: req.body.first_name,
            last_name: req.body.last_name,
            email: req.body.email,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(user.username);
                req.session.user = req.body.username;
                res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('/signup');
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }
});

app.get('/person', function(req,res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        UserModel.findOne({username: new RegExp('^'+req.session.user+'$', "i")}, function(err, user) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                res.send(user);
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});

app.put('/person', function(req,res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        console.log('Updating user');
        console.log(req.body.projects);
        UserModel.findOne({username: new RegExp('^'+req.session.user+'$', "i")}, function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            user.projects = req.body.projects;
            console.log(user.first_name + ' is here');
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('User updated');
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = null;
    res.redirect('/login');
});

app.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else if (req.params.user != req.session.user) {
        res.redirect('/' + req.session.user);
    } else {
        res.render('index');
    }
});



app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);

// JSON API
app.get('/api/name', api.name);

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.render('login');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});


/**
 * Start Server
 */

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Try moving `app.use(passport.session())` above `app.use(app.router)` so Passport can actually log in the user before your route handling functions are called.

Comment: Ok. I did that. Now I am getting the following error: TypeError: Object #<Schema> has no method 'findOne'. Have you seen this before?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that I am messing up the sessions. I'm not really using the passport session; I just created my own. Working to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I finally just removed the line app.user(passport.session()) and everything works fine now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm I wonder what it broke? Glad it's fixed!